# Draw hemispheres on top of area?

Tags: shapes, images, 3d, batch-processing

It's a completely new area for me to generate 3D structures out of 2D image. I'd like to generate spherical hemispheres on top of every white blops. How could this be possible and with what tool? I mostly use Python and matlab. The idea is that from the diameter, it shouldn't be too hard to calculate an hemisphere that could fit at that spot...

With ImageJ and python you can easily get the surface/radius of every island. I'd like to find the best way to generate hemisphere on top of every white areas.

[image: SEM image of gold nanoislands]

Comment: I am now considering Bézier surface to solve this problem.